# I am looking to bootstrap a USD and GBP yield curve: what are some of the futures and swaps I can use that are findable on Bloomberg?

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, bootstrapping

- Getting overnight-to-12 month LIBOR on Bloomberg is easy.
- Had difficulty finding GBP futures (range of maturities) on Bloomberg. Any tips (both USD and GBP)?
- Swaps (maturities all the way to 30 years) data seems available, but if you have any specific products that you use (findable on Bloomberg), would appreciate a mention.
- I will need historic data for futures and swaps going back 10 years.
- I know the world is shifting from LIBOR to SOFR, but I want all the data to be for LIBOR -- this is not for a live system but for a research project.

Generally my single-day quote table should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What tenor do you want to price?

Comment: @JoshK Not sure I understand why tenor is relevant. I am not trying to price; just building a curve.

Comment: Different tenors need different reference instruments.   Pricing 30y LIBOR swaps is way different form 1y1y fwds.